# insert line break after a specific word on a page

Tags: jquery

I am trying to edit this code,

I have a list of people on my page in horizontal order, but i would like to insert a linebreak after a specific person's name.

I have a div for my line break. It's `<div class="newline">`

```
$(window).load( function(){
  $("#peoplelist p").text("Roger John");
  var html = $(this).html().split(" ");
  html = html[0] + "<br>" + html.slice(1).join(" ");
  $(this).html(html);
});
```

but this is not working, can someone help me with this?

Comment: Can you setup a jsFiddle so that we can play with the code?

Answer (score 1):

If you know the persons name you can just do this, no need for arrays and joining and what not:

Fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/9CdtL/**

**HTML**

```
<div id="peoplelist"><p>Chris Jean, Vic Sen, Roger John, Dan Vany</p></div>
```

**JS**

```
$(window).on('load',function(){
    //here I set the name-var to the name I want the linebreak after
    //Now this is quite static, but this could of course also be done using data from a database or something.
    var name = 'Roger';

    //Here I insert the linebreak after the name using 'replace()'
    $('#peoplelist p').html($('#peoplelist p').html().replace(name+' ',name+'<br>'));
});
```

The main line is this: `[string].replace(name+' ', name+'<br>');`

---

### EDIT

I changed the whole answer. Sorry, I should have been more clear that the previous answer only showed your result in the Console, nowhere on the page. It does now.

**BTW**, your use of `$(this)` is wrong, one of the reasons your code isn't working. You can only use `$(this)` inside the action-function of an element.
You are just using it on the next line from the `$("#peoplelist p").text("Roger John");` line.
Technically, in your case `$(this)` refers to the window-object, because it's inside the window-load-function. But that won't work anyway because the window isn't an element on your page that can hold content.

Comment: console does not give me an error message, but it does not inset a line break.
I have tested on the fiddle, but it does not insert it as well, http://jsfiddle.net/AthKR/1/

Comment: @user3735148 - It works now (http://jsfiddle.net/9CdtL/). I edited my whole answer, with explanation why it didn't seem to work for you

Comment: this is working in your test fiddle, but not on my site..because my site has a profile image and below the image i have the profile name. i took the div id for the full contents and tried your query, i am not able to get this to work....

Comment: can you post the HTML code, so I can get a clear picture of the situation?

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because your `$(this)` is refering to the window.

You should try this and reference the object directly.

```
$(window).load(function(){
    var $listp = $("#peoplelist p")

    $listp.text("Roger John");

    var html = $listp.html().split(" ");
    html = html[0] + "<br>" + html.slice(1).join(" ");
    $listp.html(html);
});
```

Comment: @user3735148 can you show us the complete code? HTML too please

Comment: I am not getting any error message, the function works but not inserting any linebreak.  how do i send you the html code?

Comment: @user3735148 just post it, or create a fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/ . If you are using the wrong selector it won't necessarily show an error so long as it is syntactically correct.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's the most elegant solution, but what worked well for me was emptying the text out, and then replacing it via a '.wrapInner()' function (which can incorporate HTML):

```
$('#peoplelist p').text('');

$('#peoplelist p').wrapInner('Chris<br>Jean<br>Vic<br>Sen<br>Roger<br>John<br>Dan<br>Vany');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h1d78sm9/1/